# using Two android spinners one dependent on the other

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-spinner

I have gone through so much code and tried to figure out what I am doing wrong but i am flunked and am wasting time. It would be pretty simple but I cannot figure it out..

I am developing an android app and need to put 2 spinners on one activity. the second spinner will populate based on the entry selected on the first spinner. Sounds simple right?

So here is what I wanna do. If user selects Mobile, contents from the `choosePersonalPlan` should be displayed, when users selects Large business `chooseLargeBusplan` should run and the final entry should invoke `chooseSmallMedPlan`. All I get is the items from `ChooseSmallMedPlan` displaying all the time.

heres my code. please let me know wth I am doing wrong!

## Java file

```
package com.example.mobilebillforecaster;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;


 public class Du_postpaid extends Activity {

    public Spinner catspinner,planspinner3,planspinner1,planspinner2;


    protected void onCreate(Bundle mbfSplash) {
            super.onCreate(mbfSplash);
            setContentView(R.layout.postpaid);

    chooseCategory();
    choosePersonalPlan();
    chooseLargeBusPlan();
    chooseSmallMedPlan();
    }

    public void chooseCategory() {

        catspinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.catspinner);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> catAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.ducategory, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        catAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        catspinner.setAdapter(catAdapter);

    }
    private void choosePersonalPlan(){
        planspinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.planspinner);
        List<String> planlist = new ArrayList<String>();
        planlist.add("Elite Regular Plan");
        planlist.add("Elite Super Plans");
        planlist.add("Emirati Plan");
        planlist.add("Pay As You Go");
        planlist.add("Visitor Mobile Line");
        ArrayAdapter<String> planAdapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, planlist);
        planAdapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        planspinner1.setAdapter(planAdapter1);

    }

    private void chooseLargeBusPlan(){

        planspinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.planspinner);
        List<String> planlist1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        planlist1.add("Premier Plan");
        planlist1.add("The Executive Plan");
        planlist1.add("Business Circle Plan");
        planlist1.add("Business Diamond Plan");
        ArrayAdapter<String> planAdapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, planlist1);
        planAdapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        planspinner2.setAdapter(planAdapter2);


    }
    private void chooseSmallMedPlan(){

        planspinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.planspinner);
        List<String> planlist2 = new ArrayList<String>();
        planlist2.add("Business Super Plan");
        planlist2.add("Her Business Super Plan");
        planlist2.add("Business Circle Plan");
        planlist2.add("Pay As you Go® Plus");
        ArrayAdapter<String> planAdapter3 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, planlist2);
    planAdapter3.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    planspinner2.setAdapter(planAdapter3);

    }


    public class planOnClickListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int pos,
                    long id) {

                parent.getItemAtPosition(pos);  

                if (pos==0){
                choosePersonalPlan();   
                }else if (pos==1){
                chooseLargeBusPlan();
                } else if (pos==2){
                chooseSmallMedPlan();
}
            }
            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
            }


 }
```

### XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="left" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/postp"
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/postp"
        android:textSize="30dp"

        />


    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/catspinner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/postp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:entries="@array/ducategory"
        android:prompt="@string/category_prompt"
        />

     <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/planspinner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/catspinner" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add

```
catspinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new planOnClickListener());
```

to

```
chooseCategory();
```

Here's the whole code-

```
public class TemoActivity extends Activity {

public Spinner catspinner,planspinner3,planspinner1,planspinner2;


protected void onCreate(Bundle mbfSplash) {
        super.onCreate(mbfSplash);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

chooseCategory();
choosePersonalPlan();
chooseLargeBusPlan();
chooseSmallMedPlan();
}

public void chooseCategory() {

    catspinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.catspinner);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> catAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.ducategory, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    catAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    catspinner.setAdapter(catAdapter);
    catspinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new planOnClickListener());
}
private void choosePersonalPlan(){
    planspinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.planspinner);
    List<String> planlist = new ArrayList<String>();
    planlist.add("Elite Regular Plan");
    planlist.add("Elite Super Plans");
    planlist.add("Emirati Plan");
    planlist.add("Pay As You Go");
    planlist.add("Visitor Mobile Line");
    ArrayAdapter<String> planAdapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, planlist);
    planAdapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    planspinner1.setAdapter(planAdapter1);

}

private void chooseLargeBusPlan(){

    planspinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.planspinner);
    List<String> planlist1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    planlist1.add("Premier Plan");
    planlist1.add("The Executive Plan");
    planlist1.add("Business Circle Plan");
    planlist1.add("Business Diamond Plan");
    ArrayAdapter<String> planAdapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, planlist1);
    planAdapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    planspinner2.setAdapter(planAdapter2);


}
private void chooseSmallMedPlan(){

    planspinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.planspinner);
    List<String> planlist2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    planlist2.add("Business Super Plan");
    planlist2.add("Her Business Super Plan");
    planlist2.add("Business Circle Plan");
    planlist2.add("Pay As you Go® Plus");
    ArrayAdapter<String> planAdapter3 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, planlist2);
planAdapter3.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
planspinner2.setAdapter(planAdapter3);

}


public class planOnClickListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {

         @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int pos,
                long id) {

            parent.getItemAtPosition(pos);  

            if (pos==0){
            choosePersonalPlan();   
            }else if (pos==1){
            chooseLargeBusPlan();
            } else if (pos==2){
            chooseSmallMedPlan();
 }
        }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
        }
}
```

Comment: hello.. thank you for the responses..modified the code as suggested. but now the second spinner does not populate at all! omitted the methods from the oncreate method and added the plan onclick listener, to choose category.

Comment: Dont Omit the methods from onCreate. Keep them as they are.

Comment: Hello..I added the methods as they were.. I am back to my first problem. I think I am doing something wrong in the planonclick listener by maybe not passing correct variables for the switch to occur. please advice. @ali-imran

Answer (score 0):

Omit
    choosePersonalPlan();
    chooseLargeBusPlan();
    chooseSmallMedPlan();

from onCreate() method

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are not setting the `planOnClickListener()` any where. I thing you forget to set the listener like this  `catspinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new planOnClickListener());`