# How to make a spinner populate another spinner?

Tags: java, android, arrays, string, spinner

How would you go about making a spinner populate another spinner based on the first spinners selection?

So for example:

Spinner1 items are vegetarian or meat eater.

```
  <string-array name="spinnerarray_veg_meat">
    <item >Vegetarian</item>
    <item >Meat eater</item> 
   </string-array>
```

Spinner2 would then need to display either vegetarian meal names or meat eater ones depending on spinner1's selection.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13749805/using-two-android-spinners-one-dependent-on-the-other) could be usefull for you!

Comment: If anyone has similar problems please view Oli's link above for solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this you'll have to set a `OnItemSelectedListener` on your first `Spinner` to populate the second `Spinner` programmatically.

```
spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

              if(position == 0) {
                   // Populate the Spinner2 with different values
              } else {
                   // Populate the Spinner2 with different values
              }

        }
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            return;

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to do it. One being, create an `Array` of meat items and one of vegetable items. In `onItemSelected()` of `spinner1` set the adapter for `spinner2` according to the `position`

[Spinner Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Spinner.html)

This link has many useful functions and properties available to `Spinner`s